# Case-insensitive collation still comparing case-sensitive

Tags: postgresql, collation, case-sensitive, postgresql-12

I am currently trying to create a table with a text column which will compare case **in**sensitive by default. This is because we have a third party program that executes a search on our database. The `SELECT` statements used by this program can not be altered.

The abstract problem is that we somehow need this search to be case insensitive but it currently is case sensitive.

I read that Postgres 12 does support non-deterministic collations which allow for this behavior.

I have a Postgres Server (Version PostgreSQL 12.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit) installed on a German Windows machine.

So for testing purposes, I created a new database to test on:

```
CREATE DATABASE collation_test
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

In this database I created the following collation I found in [an article about these collations](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/10/14/nondeterministic-collations.html)

```
CREATE COLLATION collat_ci (
  provider = 'icu',
  locale = 'und-u-ks-level2',
  deterministic = false
);
```

After this, I needed a table to test this collation with

```
CREATE TABLE public.person
(
    "Id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "Name" text COLLATE public.collat_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

ALTER TABLE public.person
    OWNER to postgres;

INSERT INTO person VALUES
(1, 'Robin'),
(2, 'robin');
```

So now I tried the following select query:

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT "Name" FROM person p1 WHERE p1."Id" = 1
)
= 'Robin';
```

Which returned `true` as expected as the text in the database and the literal given match completely.

But if I try the same with a lower case `r` which I would expect to match because of my collation but it still returns `false`.

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT "Name" FROM person p1 WHERE p1."Id" = 1
)
= 'robin';
```

When trying to compare both inserted rows' name to each other I still got `false` as a result:

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT "Name" FROM person p1 WHERE p1."Id" = 1 --'Robin'
)
=
(
    SELECT "Name" FROM person p2 WHERE p2."Id" = 2 --'robin'
);
```

Does anyone know why my comparison does not behave as expected and how to get it to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The version of ICU shipped with the Windows builds is a pretty old one, so maybe that's the reason.

Try

```
CREATE COLLATION collat_ci (
  provider = 'icu',
  locale = '@colStrength=secondary',
  deterministic = false
);
```

This should work with older ICU versions.

Comment: I can confirm that this is working on Windows 10 and Postgres 12.1. On CentOS 7.7 I also need to use this definition.

Comment: Checking in: Works on Win10 and Postgres 12.3

Comment: we have had some trouble with case insensitive collation and with LIKE operator resulting with an ambigous error talking about "non deterministic collation"

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question about that.