# Does PostgreSQL handle case-insensitive database as good as others?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, performance, database-design, collation

First things first, please forgive me if my question seems so naive (I am not a DBA).
I look up to see how can I make PostgreSQL case-insensitive and I found the [Nondeterministic Collations section of the official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html) useful.
I have tried the following but there was no luck.

```sql
CREATE COLLATION ci_fa (provider = icu, locale = 'fa-IR-x-icu', deterministic = false); -- also locale = 'fa-IR' and 'fa-IR.UTF8'
```

I found [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255783/222981) but the locale used there, is not based on what I am looking for. Also, the example in the docs reads as:

```sql
CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', deterministic = false);
```

This works fine but I faced with a wired behavior in sorting. If I had a non-English character in my order column the result would be different. When I have `a`, `A`, `b` and the non-English char, the result is `a`, `A`, `b`. And when I have `a`, `A`, `B` and the non-English char, the result is `A`, `a`, `B`.

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, reading a lot of articles and questions made me wondered about the following questions?

1. Having case-insensitive data impact the performance, so should I use it or not? Considering the following facts:

   - 99% of my data has no casing. *Our language is simpler so there is no Lower/Upper case in letters :)*
   - I use Full-Text indices for the search in the parts that users can input English words. *I don't know how my collation will affect Full-Text.*
   - I don't like any of the suggested solutions [here (How to make “case-insensitive” query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005302/postgresql-how-to-make-case-insensitive-query).
   - Although I use EF Core 5, I have DB functions to handle complex queries.
2. I am at the early stage of my project and for the first time, I decided to migrate to PostgreSQL from SQL Server. Should I use MySQL instead?

   - I need Persian collation (Not sure if I do, the collation in the docs handles the sorting fine but I did not test storing it - in CentOs).
   - I need Geolocation.
   - I need Full-Text.
   - And obviously, performance.

Comment: You seem to have three different questions here, two of which are opinion-based and as such not appropriate. As for your first question, since you request case-insensitive sort, both `A` and `a` have equal weight, and the engine is within its rights to return them in any order, so I don't understand what you find surprising.

Comment: @mustaccio, You are absolutely right. `a` and `A` have equal weight, so do `b` and `B`. and I am surprised because I didn't expect changing the value of one row to affect others while they have the same weight. In the end, this is not my question as I understand both results are correct however it is not consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *When I have a, A, b and the non-English char, the result is a, A, b. And when I have a, A, B and the non-English char, the result is A, a,
> B.*

It's an effect of the `deterministic` collation property being false. There is no tie-breaker between equivalent strings, so `a` may come out before `A` or the opposite. Also sorts in database are generally not [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts), because in relational theory, rows have no inherent order so sticking to the "original order" makes no sense.

If you don't like that, you may add a second order with a deterministic collation, for instance

```
ORDER BY field COLLATE "non-deterministic-collation", field COLLATE "C"
```

> *I use Full-Text indices for the search in the parts that users can input English words. I don't know how my collation will affect
> Full-Text.*

It doesn't. The full text search parser is mostly influenced by the `lc_ctype` property of the database. There is even a specific error associated to forcing a collation when extracting a `tsvector` from a string:

```
=> select to_tsvector('abc') collate "C";
ERROR:  collations are not supported by type tsvector
```

> *I need Persian collation (Not sure if I do, the collation in the docs handles the sorting fine but I did not test storing it - in CentOs).*

When a database is created, it does inherit a collation from the template database, or get it from the `lc_collate` or `locale` clause if specified explicitly. That's the default collation for all sorts and string comparisons in this database.

If you use Linux in an UTF-8 encoding with `fa_IR` locale, the `lc_collate` of your database is probably `fa_IR.UTF-8`, so it does use a Persian collation implicitly. There is no clear indication in your question that your application really needs to create custom collations beyond that.

The details for creating collation can be fine [here](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/10/14/nondeterministic-collations.html) and [here](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Diagnostics/Locales/LongForm.htm) and to create Persian collation the following can be used.

```sql
CREATE COLLATION the_name (provider = icu, locale = 'fa-IR@colStrength=secondary', deterministic = false);
```